# Redirecting all 404 pages in Wordpress is not good SEO, but what is?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, web-crawlers, 404

Maybe a silly question, but if you have a 404 error, than `Google` does not want to index your site. Of course you are going to say: 'who said that, that's not true', I know... But Google does not like 8000 `404 errors` either :) And that's the case on my site...

Well, I have to say that the structure of my website is built this way. People can post from the front end and link to non-existing posts. That's fine with me, but not fine with Google. I have read many topics here and I saw that `redirecting` these pages to the homepage `(301)` is not good too...

But what is than? In `Webmasters` I am seeing 8000 crawl errors, which are leading to bad results in Google (I know that, because before that it was much better). What should I do know? What is a solution if 404 and 301's are not?

Comment: Can you provide more information about your site and/or the URL? Why would users post links to non-existent posts?

Comment: It's a dictionary site where people can make up words. The url is not important. Let's say you have this information.... can you provide an answer? How bad is this for SEO?